# The first Halachic compendium that does not follow the Mishnaic order (not שו"ת)?

Tags: jewish-books, halacha-theory

Since Abraham, the original Oral Torah allegedly consisted of the currently known 6 Sdarim (although the number of Masechtot was much bigger, up to 6000?).

The Mishnah and naturally the Talmud are also arranged by the Sdarim. The interpreters of the Talmud also followed that order and wrote their notes alongside the Talmud.

Who was the first to write a **stand-alone Halachic compendium (not a שו"ת) that did not follow the Mishnaic order** (Berachot, Moed etc), "inventing" an order of its own (or was it Rambam's היד החזקה)?

NB: *As I've checked, it seems that the books הלכות פסוקות and [הלכות גדולות](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=11512&st=&pgnum=17&hilite=) both follow the Mishnaic order (by the Seder of the Talmud).*

Comment: Prob. ‘[Halachot Pesukot](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/הלכות_פסוקות)’ by [Yehudai Gaon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehudai_Gaon).

Comment: By *write* I assume you mean *publish* - as in for publish consumption.

Comment: How about the Torah?

Comment: @AlBerko If your assertion is based on the linked Wiki. article you should know it is not accurate. From my recollection of the fragments preserved, as discussed by various scholars of the Gaonim, I believe it follows *halachic* topics found in the talmudic *sedarim* but I do not think the compendium was akin to the Rif. Do you have alternative sources?

Comment: Some midrashei halacha

Comment: Sheiltot of Achai Gaon?

Comment: Your question is confusing; does it have to be a completely new order, or can it follow something other than the mishna (like the Torah)?

Comment: When you say Halachic Compendium, do you mean a work that encompasses all of Halacha, or a specific topic? For instance: Would a work like Megillas Taanis count, since it’s a Halacha Sefer, or no, since it’s not on all of Halacha? What about Shas Bavli? That’s not on *all* of Halacha - much of Zeraim and Taharos goes untouched. Yes the latter follows the order of Mishnayos. Not what I’m asking.

Comment: @DoubleAA i think we have a consensus on sheiltos, can we just make it an answer?

Comment: hey! what happened to midrash? are those not sifrei halacha?

Comment: @DonielF I did mean a compendium like Rambam's 14 books. Actually, my following question is how one can change the order of the Oral Law - so I am looking for who was the first to stray from the 6 Sdarim.

Comment: @heshy She'iltot might not qualify for the criterion  of "not a שו"ת"

Comment: btw, the tur sort of follows four out of the six sedarim, with orach chaim as moed, with berachos from zraim thrown in, even haezer as nashim, choshen mishpat as nezikin, and yoreh deah as the relevant parts of kodshim and taharos

Answer (score 2):

Sheiltos Derav Achai Gaon is a commentary on many Halachic issues and follows the order of the Parsha in the Torah written in the 9th century.

Sefer Hamitzvos of Rav Saadia Gaon was also written in the 9th century following the order of Mitzvos in the Torah.

Also Siddur deRav Amram Gaon from aroud the same time follows the Tefilla and gives Halachic rulings.